# Debian: package updates in stable distribution

Tags: debian, dpkg

I am running Debian Wheezy, which is the current stable Debian distribution. In my `/etc/apt/sources.list`, I have something like the following:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian wheezy main
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian-security/ wheezy/updates main
```

When I run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, I would expect that only security updates will be installed. However, I see that there are other packages which want to be updated, such as:

```
dpkg (1.16.10) -> (1.16.12)
```

could somebody please explain what is the debian update policy? Why were these packaged updated? I was under the impression, that only security issues are being fixed in stable distribution.

Comment: See http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/pkgs.html#upload-stable for the policy. See http://ftp-master.metadata.debian.org/changelogs//main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.16.12_changelog for the changelog itself - it only fixes bugs (or regressions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian updates main mirror sometimes. That update contains all security updates from last release and some not-security updates.
For example last minor update was [12 Oct](http://www.debian.org/News/2013/20131012) and that update contains dpkg improvements